# In SSRS design document i need to map one field as "Customer Number/ Position Number"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

While i'm preparing the SSRS design document by gathering fields/dataset fields from my report I had faced one error as:

The field is "customer Order/Postion/Sequence" is the header description.
I need to pull the details and print the values in the report in the same manner/order.
I'm facing

> Error for this field in the design preview.

Could you please help me how to insert / in between two fields as customer oreder/Postion/Sequence?

For ex. take:

```
customer order = tccom_cuno
Position = tcfcs100_pono
Sequence = tcmcs100_sqnb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display more than field in a single text box cell, along with any other text, without needing to adjust your dataset or use expressions.

Double-click on a text box, as you do to type a value. Without any text selected, right-click and select '**Create Placeholder...**'. Select a value from your data set as the Value - you probably won't need to set any other properties at this stage.

You can do this for each of your three fields, and you can type the / between each placeholder as plain text.

[image: Multiple Fields in a TextBox, with forward-slashes between]